# Iterating through file sizes recursively

Tags: python, windows, for-loop, md5

Hi I have created a mini program to get the `MD5 hash` of all files in the directory the script is located.

My problem is when I generate the `get_size()` of the files I end up with only one line in my `filelist.md5.txt` and `get_size()` seems to be outputting the entire directory's sum instead of each individual files size.
How can I output individual files size in this script?

I get this output in the `filelist.md5.txt` file:

```
#
#  GENERATE_FILELIST
#  (filename)    (filesize)    (md5)    (major_version)    (minor_version)
#

Test_2.txt                                   190         dea9fe052f1abf71bac7421c732b0475      ----           ----
```

However I want to get this output:

```
#
#  GENERATE_FILELIST
#  (filename)    (filesize)    (md5)    (major_version)    (minor_version)
#

MD5.bat                                      filesize              b9a7c825517002e0da8e980c2c2c2cef      ----           ----
MD5.py                                       filesize              b61124e8bef473d377f59aa0964174ce      ----           ----
MD5test.bat                                  filesize              f29d68f9721c57d648164cae79dac71b      ----           ----
MD5test.py                                   filesize              a7a3c45ebe1aca82f57591c7fccd6cfc      ----           ----
MD5v1.bat                                    filesize              e5e7407117845a2413fe667fe7a2f681      ----           ----
MD5v1.py                                     filesize              55ab90b5a623548825a0b40406fcdde2      ----           ----
MD5v2.bat                                    filesize              e9e31aaa62f6f37572cf89a03860cb96      ----           ----
MD5v3.bat                                    filesize              559c0e9ed05fc9b4884c83bc3e04f8fd      ----           ----
MD5v3.py                                     filesize              d20a8841f3c37d28fd3b74847731e212      ----           ----
Test_2.txt                                   filesize              dea9fe052f1abf71bac7421c732b0475      ----           ----
```

Code so far:

```
import glob
import hashlib
import sys
import os


filenames = glob.glob('*.*')

# truncate the file to zero length before opening
f1 = open(os.path.expanduser(sys.path[0]) + '\\filelist.md5.txt', 'w')

#'a' will append the file, rather than write over whatever else you put in it like 'w' 
with open('filelist.md5.txt', 'a') as f:
        print >> f,''
        print >> f,'#'
        print >> f,'#  GENERATE_FILELIST'
        print >> f,'#  (filename)    (filesize)    (md5)    (major_version)    (minor_version)'
        print >> f,'#'
        print >> f,''
f.close()

# print to console
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
        print '. -- ',filename, ' ---------- ', hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()

# get the size of each file
def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for fn in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
            return total_size

    #'a' will append the file, rather than write over whatever else you put in it like 'w'
with open('filelist.md5.txt', 'a') as f:

        print >> f,'{:44}'.format(filename), get_size(),'       ', hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest(),'    ','----','         ','----'

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_size()` is written to return the size of the whole directory, which is not what you're looking for.

```
dir=r'specify\path\here'
with open('filelist.md5.txt', 'w') as fx:
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, f)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            # specify anything else you want to write inside fx.write()
            fx.write(f + "\t\t" + str(os.path.getsize(path)) + "\n")
```

The above code writes the file name and size separated by tabs, and in separate lines.

You don't have to explicitly close when you're doing `with open('filelist.md5.txt', 'a') as f:`

Comment: Thanks, when I add `hashlib.md5(f).hexdigest()` to `fx.write` I get weird hexdigests..

Comment: @MALKAVIAN without seeing what & how you've added and the 'weird' result, I can't help. Maybe, you can post another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try This ( Works Better for larg_file, none_ascci_format_files_names, whitout glob module, and error_handling ):

```
import hashlib, os, hashlib, sys

your_target_folder = "."  # put your folder or just this "."


def get_size(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return str(st.st_size)


def get_minor_version(filename):
    # Your Code ...
    return "minor_version"


def get_major_version(filename):
    # Your Code ...
    return "major_version"


def get_md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


# this function works for none ascii files names ( like chinese format )!!
def sys_out(out_data):
    try:
        print(out_data)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        if sys.version_info >= (3,):
            print(out_data.encode('utf8').decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
        else:
            print(out_data.encode('utf8'))


def make_beautiful_terminal_output(get_list):

    col_width = max(len(word) for word in get_list) + 3  # padding

    buffer_last = []
    for row in get_list:
        buffer_last.append("".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in get_list))

    return buffer_last[0]


def print_header():

    header_tag = "(filename)                         (filesize)                         (md5)                             (major_version)                    (minor_version)\n"

    with open("filelist.md5.txt", "a") as my_header:
        my_header.write(header_tag)

    print(header_tag)


print_header()

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(your_target_folder):

    for items in filenames:
        file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))

        try:

            my_last_data = [items, get_size(file_full_path), get_md5(file_full_path), get_major_version(file_full_path), get_minor_version(file_full_path)]

            terminal_output = make_beautiful_terminal_output(my_last_data)

            sys_out(terminal_output)

            re_buffer = terminal_output + "\n"
            with open("filelist.md5.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as my_save_file:
                my_save_file.write(re_buffer)

        except:
            sys_out("Error On " + str(file_full_path))
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is the output file contains the literal header info instead of the values. Using python 2.7 btw.

Comment: @MALKAVIAN: so... may you vote +1 for this answer? for other users who wants this answer too.

Comment: @MALKAVIAN: do you know cython?

Comment: @MALKAVIAN: with cython you can convert any kind of .py file to c or c++ codes!! with jython you can convert .py to java format ( .jar ), with kivy you can make android application with python!! with django you can make web service or website with python! with pyqt and tkinter you can make GUI program on windows and unix os! with pyinstaller you can compile your .py file to .exe....enough? python is life :))))